# How do I make friendly_id URLs for city and state like united-states/texas/austin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources, friendly-id

So I have 2 different links:

```
united-states/texas/austin
```

and:

```
united-states/colorado/austin-14be76ea-77e2-4f0e-8540-0103ad72cd7a
```

I want the second one to be simply:

```
united-states/colorado/austin
```

So how do I get friendly_id to stop creating unique slugs, and instead ensure that city slug is unique when scoped by country and state?

Also when in my controller, how do I locate the correct city, scoped by country and state?

```
@city = City.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

This just looks at the slug, and doesn't care about city being a nested resource.

Here is my setup:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :scoped, :scope => [:homeland, :region]
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :homeland
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :scoped, :scope => :homeland
  belongs_to :homeland
  has_many :cities
end

#Had to use Homeland as Country was in use
class Homeland < ActiveRecord::Base 
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :regions
  has_many :cities, through: :regions
end
```

Routes.rb

```
  resources :homelands, :path => '' do
    resources :regions, :path => '' do 
      resources :cities, :path => ''
    end
  end
```

**Update: Here you go Michal**

[image]

**Update 2: My fix for now**

Remove:

```
  resources :homelands, :path => '' do
    resources :regions, :path => '' do 
      resources :cities, :path => ''
    end
  end
```

Add:

```
  get "local/:id", to: "homelands#show", as: 'homeland'
  get "local/:homeland_id/:id", to: "regions#show", as: 'region'
  get "local/:homeland_id/:region_id/:id", to: "cities#show", as: 'city'
```

For Links:

```
<%= link_to region.name, region_path(region.slug, homeland_id: @homeland.slug) %>
```

Comment: Which version of FriendlyId do you use exactly? And which Rails version?

Comment: friendly_id (5.0.4), rails (4.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in FriendlyId which causes that. See https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/536

If you kick my a** a little maybe I will get myself to pull request a patch finally.

Comment: I was about to revert the edit until I saw this answer. Well played.